# How to set time gap for one view to otherview

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uiviewanimation

In my application I want to set certain time gap while going from one view to other view. Here my code. It's not working.

```
-(IBAction)learnvu
{
    CATransition *anim = [CATransition animation];
    learnview *lview=[[learnview alloc]initWithNibName:@"learnview" bundle:nil];
    [anim setDuration:0.40];
    [anim setType:kCATransitionPush];
    [anim setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:lview animated:YES]; 
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for either: a) a time delay then push with an animation or b)push with an animation over a period of time

Comment: i want to go with b)push with an animation left to right over a period of time @CStreel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to animate between views and you don't need to support devices earlier then 4.0 then try using UIView's `animateWithDuration:animations:` documentation can be found here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html